# Are questions asking for references on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

[Is there a research-based book that discusses feline social interactions and cues?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/625/is-there-a-research-based-book-that-discusses-feline-social-interactions-and-cue)

So, do we want these types of questions?